# How to divide a matrix by the sum of rows and it has zeros

Tags: r, matrix

I am pretty new to R and I have a loop which gives sometimes a matrix like this:

```
        1 2
  FALSE 0 0
  TRUE  0 2
```

I need to do as follows:
If the two cells in a single row have zeros replace them by 0.5
If one of the cells is not zero divide by the sum of the row

so the result of this will be:

```
         1    2
  FALSE 0.5 0.5
  TRUE  0    1
```

Any idea please?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you Dan, but that solved part of the problem and the second row still has 0 2 as the original matrix.

Comment: Fixed. I jumped the gun before grasping the second part of the problem

Comment: On noticing the green checkmark successively being awarded to all 3 answers: @Amani, FYI, you can only award one answer the green checkmark. Typically, you don't want to re-award it when additional answers are provided after the first answer, unless they're substantial improvements. That removes the bonus and checkmark from previous answers. Award it to the one single best answer, and lean towards earlier answers (rather than answers where someone re-factored or combined earlier answers).

Comment: Oh! thank you Dan for telling me that, I did not know :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is `x`,

```
(x <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 2), 2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    2    

zero_rows <- as.logical(rowSums(x != 0))
x[zero_rows,] <- x[zero_rows,]/sum(x[zero_rows,])
x[rowSums(x) == 0, ] <- rep(0.5, ncol(x))
    x
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.5  0.5
# [2,]  0.0  1.0
```

This will work for a matrix (2 dimensional array) of arbitrary size

@akrun's suggested edit, constructing `zero_rows` with `rowSums(x != 0)` instead of `apply(x, 1, function(r) 0 %in% r)` should make this even more efficient.

Comment: You could construct the `zero_rows` with `rowSums` i.e. `!!rowSums(x != 0)`

Comment: oh, yes, that's lovely! adding the edit. I'll convert to logical with `as.logical`, rather than `!!`, though. Since we're not golfing.

Answer (score 1):

Let `x <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 2), 2))`

```
 t(apply(x,1,function(y)if(all(!y))replace(y,!y,0.5)else if(any(!y))y/sum(y) else y))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5  0.5
[2,]  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dan and Onyambu! Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 2), 2)

t(apply(x, 1L, function(y) ifelse(all(y == 0), return(rep(0.5, length(y))), return(y/sum(y)))))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  0.5  0.5
#[2,]  0.0  1.0
```